# With Screencast removed in Blender 2.8, what is a good alternative to capture a timelapse of your work?

Tags: screencast

I have been wanting to record timelapses of my work to share with my friends as we learn Blender together.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DSA5nwaomU8) shows that in pre-Blender v2.8 there was the 'Screencast' (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>) feature that would save images of the entire Blender window at specified intervals. My understanding is that this feature has [now been removed](https://developer.blender.org/rB46dceefc353a).

Looking on YouTube I have noticed a lot of videos with 'Eevee timelapse' ([this video for e.g.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RaQ-ly4b9gI)) in the name, does that mean Eevee can capture the whole workflow timelapse? If so would you be able to explain the process?

I am basically trying to find out what the standard way of recording timelapse videos in Blender 2.8, now that 'Screencast' is out. Or are most people simply screen capping with things like OBS?